# high availability of spark driver

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, high-availability

running a spark application in yarn cluster mode my driver somehow seems to have restarted. this results in reprocessing all the data from scratch (I was writing several tables and hashing some data, some tables were already complete).

Is there a way to prevent this from happening and introduce high availability for the driver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that your driver was restarted is Spark's interpretation of HA. Restarts are triggered when errors occur.

You can control the amount of attempts with the following property though

```
spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts
```

Pass that on to your hadoop configuration settings in you job conf.

Comment: Is there something to tell yarn (preemption is enabled for this particular queue to be more careful with the application masters? Also I guess that checkpointing would not really help here.

Comment: Well, the most common reason for failures is lack of memory - fine tuning your spark app to accommodate the amount of available memory is key here, i.e. ascertain that your spark driver has enough memory and that doesn't exceed the yarn limits.